# C++ ofStream: "<<" vs "put"

Tags: c++, ofstream

Being new to C++, I am confused about what `<<` and `put()` means while using `ofstream` to write to a text file. I tried to experiment with the two following styles as follows:

Approach 1:

```
void writeTester() {
    std::ofstream oFile("Resources/tst.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc);
    std::vector<int> v{ 1,2,3,4 };
    for (int i = 0;i < 4;i++) {
        oFile.put(v[i]);
        //casting to character pointer and writing also produced similar result
        //oFile.put(*(char*)&v[i]);
    }
    oFile.close();
}
```

Approach 2:

```
void writeTester() {
    std::ofstream oFile("Resources/tst.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc);
    std::vector<int> v{ 1,2,3,4 };
    for (int i = 0;i < 4;i++) {
        oFile << v[i];
    }
    oFile.close();
}
```

While Approach 2 wrote the expected result to file (1234), Approach 1 wrote some garbage value to the file.

What is the difference between the 2 styles, and when to use which one? Also, what is the correct way to use Approach 1 to have "1234" as the output written to the file?

Comment: Did you [read the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/put)?

Comment: Unformatted output of a character with (ASCII) value 1 (i.e., `'\1'`) is not the same as a formatted output of an integer with value 1 (which will be formatted as character `'1'`, this is ASCII value 49).

Comment: casting to character is not enough, you are just changing the size of the pointer which will truncate the value of an integer to a maximum of 1 byte. You must convert v[i] to a proper character like c = '0'+v[i]

Comment: No, Approach 1 doesn't write garbage value. It just write the unformatted value to the file. Use `hexdump -C output_file_path` you could check the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, using the '<<' operator means certain overloads can be used, which means writing integer values (as in your case) will mean they're converting to their string representations before being written to the file.

Using put, however, will write a single byte to the stream. This means your 4 byte `int` will be truncated to a single byte, thus writing nonsense data to your file.

[Here's](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/put/) the documentation for ofstream::put.
[And here's](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/) the documentation for ofstream.

For completion, and to spark your interest, here's an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), where you can look up the values you were writing to the file. Depends on the byte order (endianness) of your machine, which char is written. On LE machines it should be NUL, but I get confused myself sometimes and mix up the byte orders in my head so please take that last sentence with a grain of salt.